# Easiest way to shorten a list to n elements in Robot Framework

Tags: unit-testing, robotframework

We are using Robot Framework to test our system. In some cases, due to hardware misconfigurations, a long list of errors is produced, that is flooding the log and slows down the test.

Now, I want to shorten the list of errors messages to say 100. How can I shorten a list to 100 in Robot Framework with a one-liner?

My first attempt would be

```
@{list}=   get Errors
@{sliced_list}=   Get Slice From List   @{list}  end=100
```

But, this would possible fail, in case the List does not contain 100 elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, this would possible fail, in case the List does not contain 100 elements.

It won't, that keyword does in python `list_[start:end]`, which doesn't fail if the "end" is greater than the list's length.

Comment: Many thanks for the fast reply. Seems, that I have to brush up my python.